# How to create a custom module for image and video upload in Admin product page magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, admin, product-attribute, product-images, image-upload

I want to create a custom module for image and video upload in Admin product page magento2.2.5?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's one big task you want to do. You have to show what you have done and then people can help you.